# How to be able to be used both integer and float in pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I want to be used both integer (s_int) and float (s_flt).

My code can be used only integer. If to change `bundle = s_int | s_flt | ident` to `bundle = s_flt | s_int | ident`, this code will be able to be used only float.

```
import pyparsing as p

ident = p.Word(p.alphas + '_', p.alphanums + '_.')
s_int = p.Word(p.nums    ).setParseAction(lambda tokens: int  (tokens[0]))
s_flt = p.Word(p.nums+'.').setParseAction(lambda tokens: float(tokens[0]))

bundle = s_int | s_flt | ident
member = p.Group(ident + p.Suppress(':') + bundle)
parser = p.delimitedList (member) 
print (parser.parseString("id: 0, name: ex1, x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z:5.0"))
print (parser.parseString("id: 1, name: ex2, x: 1  , y: 2.0"))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this may do what you want.

```
import pyparsing as p

ident = p.Word(p.alphanums + '_.')
s_int = p.Word(p.nums    )
s_flt = p.Word(p.nums+'.')

bundle = s_flt | s_int | ident
member = p.Group(ident + p.Suppress(':') + bundle)
parser = p.delimitedList (member) 
print (parser.parseString("id: 0, name: ex1, x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z:5.0"))
print (parser.parseString("id: 1, name: ex2, x: 1  , y: 2.0"))
```

Output:

```
[['id', '0'], ['name', 'ex1'], ['x', '1.0'], ['y', '2.0'], ['z', '5.0']]
[['id', '1'], ['name', 'ex2'], ['x', '1'], ['y', '2.0']]
```

There were two things I noticed about the original code.

- `setParseAction` with `lambda` has the effect of *replacing* one or more tokens that it's given with the result of the `lambda`. I don't think this is what you wanted since the result of the each of `lambda`s is of a numeric type.
- Since `s_int` was placed first in the `bundle` parser this parser would always accept a float constant, rather than an integer constant. I put the `s_flt` parser first.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Word(nums+'.') but it also accepted none float like 1.1. or 1.1.1

I tried Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums) but I could not find out why pyparsing didn't catch up the float (it seems like it should work).

I ended up using for catching int + float + minus:
number = Optional('-') + Word(nums) + Optional('.' + Word(nums))

Not sure it is the best solution but it may help people in the same case as me (I am parsing some custom rules to check their validity).